# connector without a name?

Tags: connector, identification

I am trying to find the name of a particular electronics connector. the connector is often used in auto stereos to attach a faceplate to the main body (detachable face radio). this is much like a dual row edge connector, however the contacts are offset. 10 contacts on each side, hard plastic barrier between each contact.

Comment: Have you got a photo as this question is not answerable ATM.

Comment: I don't believe there is a standard connector for head units. A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I will take a picture tonight, update later. I've searched the Internet for days, with many different descriptors, no luck.
Thank you,

Comment: You're definitely looking for board-to-board connectors, try that as a search term.

Answer (score 1):

i posted pics last night, but they have not been "reviewed" yet I guess? With the info I got from shamtam, I found "Board to Board Panel Connectors"
http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=detachable_boardtoboard&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction

Thanks